# Css titles with div over another div

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to customize a div. I've found some solutions but doesn't seem to work for me when I have two lines of text using span. Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve with two different types of text.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code I have and it seems to be note working in terms of the background. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.container {
border: 1px solid #000; 
padding: 10px; 
text-align: center;
}

.content {
margin: -40px 0 20px 0; 
text-align: center;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;  text-transform:uppercase;
border: 1px solid #000; 
}

.title {color: red;}
.subtitle {color: green;}
```

```html
<br />&nbsp;<br />

<div class="container"><div class="content"><span class="title">Title</span><br /><span class="subtitle">Subtitle</span></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non mi eget quam lobortis porta. Ut sagittis sem a fringilla ultricies. </div>
```

Comment: Can you upload the image to imgur? img42.com is blocked at work.

Comment: @SecuriTree Hahaa it's the opposite for me, could you keep both? :)

Comment: Sorry guys will do both links.

Comment: @SecuriTree http://i.imgur.com/lXQ7lis.png

Comment: Unclear what issue you are having, the code snippet and image look very similar.

Comment: Both of those images look identical

Comment: Also both images are simliar to me

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, some people could not view the image from the link i attached so I attached another source, they are the same image. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.title {
  color: red;
}
.subtitle {
  color: green;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non mi eget quam lobortis porta. Ut sagittis sem a fringilla ultricies.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `position` for this:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.container {border: 2px solid #000; position: relative; min-height: 250px; width: 250px; margin: 100px auto;}
.container .header {position: absolute; border: 2px solid #000; background-color: #fff; width: 50%; text-align: center; left: 25%; top: -40px; background: #ccc;}
h1 {color: red; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.5;}
h2 {color: green; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.5; padding: 0 0 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if i wasn't using this in a complicated wordpress layout with numerous other elements that can be messed up by resets. Also I need it to be responsive. this version I have now works perfectly and adapts well when placed with columns of similar nature but i just need the title box to contract to fit the title & subtitle.

Comment: What exactly is your problem then? Can't you change your WP layout?

Comment: No i'm using a responsive theme in WP (theme X) with 3 columns, which means I cannot specify in pixels but rather percentages so that the responsiveness remains and won't get altered when users view in different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all those that helped in the end I figured out the best solution for me was to adjust the width and a few other things. *this solution worked best for me since I'm using several columns and in a responsive wordpress theme, putting up this solution in case someone is interested.

My main concern was that it be flexible and not set in pixels, and that the title and subtitle box should not be complete width but rather just fill the title background. This solution is flexible and I adjust the width percentage based on different columns (created additional spans etc).

My solution below:

```css
.container {
border: 1px solid #000; 
padding: 10px; 
text-align: center;
}

.content {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 22px 15px 25px;  
    text-transform:uppercase;
line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 170px;
}

.title {color: red;}
.subtitle {color: green;}
```

```html
<br />&nbsp;<br />

<div class="container"><div class="content"><span class="title">Title</span><br /><span class="subtitle">Subtitle</span></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non mi eget quam lobortis porta. Ut sagittis sem a fringilla ultricies. </div>
```